# Show that this set is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]_{deg\leq n}$ denote the set of all polynomials in $x$ with degree less than or equal to $n$. Show that A is denumerable.

I know that set of all polynomials with integer coefficients is countable but how can I prove this problem ?

Comment: How can you uniquely define a polynomial with degree less then $n$ using $n$ integers?

Comment: @ItamarShmelo $P(x)=a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$ I guess

Comment: Think about it as $(a_0, a_1 ,...a_n)$

Comment: @ItamarShmelo and after that ?

Comment: this is just $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ right?

Comment: @ItamarShmelo yes it is. But I really dont get it. can you please give answer if possible I am very new in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is in bijection with $\mathbb Z^{n+1}$ which is countable as a finite product of countable sets.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a bit more

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is countable, $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ is countable. And proceed then by induction.

Comment: I really dont get it. can you please give answer if possible I am very new in this topic. Would really appreciate you help.

Comment: I suggest that you Google. Those are very common results.

Comment: I have tried that already but couldnt find anything related to this problem. If you could find can you please give me the link ?